# Possible causes of ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid error with message "Could not find table 'active_records'" in a Rails project on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rubygems, devise

I used devise to create the users table, all the names are correct, I only use one model and there are no typos anywhere. When I start the server I get to the login page. If I try to login or register, I get the following error after clicking the login/register button. The project was created on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

**ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in CalcController#input
Could not find table 'active_records'
**

```
  def authenticate_user!
    if user_signed_in?
      puts "User #{current_user} is authenticated"
    else
      puts "User isn't authenticated"
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

I don't understand why rails is looking for a table with that name when I haven't even created anything like that.

I reset the table and created again, created a table named active_records, but nothing helped. I still get this error

Here's the stack trace.

```
activerecord (7.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:458:in `table_structure'
activerecord (7.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:109:in `columns'
activerecord (7.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:346:in `block in columns'
activerecord (7.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:345:in `fetch'
activerecord (7.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:345:in `columns'
activerecord (7.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:354:in `block in columns_hash'
activerecord (7.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:353:in `fetch'
activerecord (7.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:353:in `columns_hash'
activerecord (7.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:58:in `columns_hash'
activerecord (7.1.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:188:in `columns_hash'
activerecord (7.1.2) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:618:in `load_schema!'
activerecord (7.1.2) lib/active_record/attributes.rb:264:in `load_schema!'
activerecord (7.1.2) lib/active_record/encryption/encryptable_record.rb:127:in `load_schema!'
activerecord (7.1.2) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:563:in `block in load_schema'
activerecord (7.1.2) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:560:in `synchronize'
activerecord (7.1.2) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:560:in `load_schema'
activerecord (7.1.2) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:441:in `attribute_types'
activerecord (7.1.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:256:in `_has_attribute?'
activerecord (7.1.2) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
orm_adapter (0.5.0) lib/orm_adapter/to_adapter.rb:5:in `to_adapter'
devise (4.9.3) lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:280:in `find_first_by_auth_conditions'
devise (4.9.3) lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:276:in `find_for_authentication'
devise (4.9.3) lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb:217:in `find_for_database_authentication'
devise (4.9.3) lib/devise/strategies/database_authenticatable.rb:10:in `authenticate!'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/strategies/base.rb:55:in `_run!'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/proxy.rb:372:in `block in _run_strategies_for'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/proxy.rb:365:in `each'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/proxy.rb:365:in `_run_strategies_for'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/proxy.rb:335:in `_perform_authentication'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/proxy.rb:133:in `authenticate!'
devise (4.9.3) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:19:in `create'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:224:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:165:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:259:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (7.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:121:in `block in run_callbacks'
actiontext (7.1.2) lib/action_text/rendering.rb:23:in `with_renderer'
actiontext (7.1.2) lib/action_text/engine.rb:69:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Engine>'
activesupport (7.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:130:in `instance_exec'
activesupport (7.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:130:in `block in run_callbacks'
activesupport (7.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:141:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:258:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:25:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:74:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (7.1.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (7.1.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:58:in `instrument'
activesupport (7.1.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:73:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:261:in `process_action'
activerecord (7.1.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:32:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:160:in `process'
actionview (7.1.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:40:in `process'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:227:in `dispatch'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:309:in `dispatch'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:21:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:51:in `serve'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:51:in `block in serve'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:131:in `block in find_routes'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:124:in `each'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:124:in `find_routes'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:882:in `call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (3.0.8) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:20:in `call'
rack (3.0.8) lib/rack/etag.rb:29:in `call'
rack (3.0.8) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:43:in `call'
rack (3.0.8) lib/rack/head.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/permissions_policy.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:33:in `call'
rack-session (2.0.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:272:in `context'
rack-session (2.0.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:689:in `call'
activerecord (7.1.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:654:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (7.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'
web-console (4.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (7.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
railties (7.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (7.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:135:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (7.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:39:in `tagged'
activesupport (7.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:135:in `tagged'
activesupport (7.1.2) lib/active_support/broadcast_logger.rb:240:in `method_missing'
railties (7.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:92:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:28:in `call'
rack (3.0.8) lib/rack/method_override.rb:28:in `call'
rack (3.0.8) lib/rack/runtime.rb:24:in `call'
activesupport (7.1.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:59:in `block in call'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:24:in `collect_events'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:58:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:25:in `call'
rack (3.0.8) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:114:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:141:in `call'
railties (7.1.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:529:in `call'
puma (6.4.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:272:in `call'
puma (6.4.2) lib/puma/request.rb:100:in `block in handle_request'
puma (6.4.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:378:in `with_force_shutdown'
puma (6.4.2) lib/puma/request.rb:99:in `handle_request'
puma (6.4.2) lib/puma/server.rb:464:in `process_client'
puma (6.4.2) lib/puma/server.rb:245:in `block in run'
puma (6.4.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:155:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Can you add an actual stack trace? Just the error isn't very helpful.

Comment: What do the class definitions of the `User` and `ApplicationModel` look like?

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/StatementInvalid.html